# How to find types that are direct descendants of a base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, types, descendant

I need to get all types of an assembly that inherits some base class but only the first descendants. For instance if I have:

```
class Base
{

}

class FirstClass : Base
{

}

class SecondClass : FirstClass
{

}
```

Now

```
var directOnes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)));
```

should return only `FirstClass` and not `SecondClass`. Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `IsSubclassOf()` you can use [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx)

e.g.

```
var directOnes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == (typeof(Base)));
```

(FYI: I don't think there's a way to find the *interfaces* that a type directly implements.)

Comment: Ok, I need not think of interfaces at this moment, so that's fine.