# Get all last descendants of a base type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, types, descendant

This question is an opposite of [How to find types that are direct descendants of a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476073/how-to-find-types-that-are-direct-descendants-of-a-base-class)

If this is the inheritance hierarchy I have,

```
class Base
{

}



class Derived1 : Base
{

}

class Derived1A : Derived1
{

}

class Derived1B : Derived1
{

}



class Derived2 : Base
{

}
```

I need a mechanism to find all the sub types of `Base` class in a particular assembly which are at the end of the inheritance tree. In other words,

```
SubTypesOf(typeof(Base))
```

should give me

```
-> { Derived1A, Derived1B, Derived2 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have come up with. Not sure if some more elegant/efficient solutions exist..

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetLastDescendants(this Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsClass)
        throw new Exception(t + " is not a class");

    var subTypes = t.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(t)).ToArray();
    return subTypes.Where(x => subTypes.All(y => y.BaseType != x));
}
```

And for sake of completeness, I will repost the answer for direct descendants given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476153/661933)

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetDirectDescendants(this Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsClass)
        throw new Exception(t + " is not a class");

    return t.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == t);
}
```

Comment: What about Derived1 ?

Comment: @I4V Derived1 is not at the end of the hierarchy tree. It has children. I had a special requirement today where I wanted the youngest lot :)